# Navigation menu on javascript. DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, navigation

i have issues, how can I know for example contain `<li>` children `<ul>` or not?
thx all!

Comment: We all have issues...  You are not alone ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a `<ul>` element contains any `<li>` elements, you only need to use one selector -

```
var elements = $('ul#selector').find('li');
if (elements.length){
  // the <ul> has child <li> elements
}else{
  // no <li> elements found
}
```

This of course can be written in a single conditional statement -

```
var childElements =  $('ul#selector > li').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll("li > ul").length
```

or check `querySelector` for `null`

```
if (!document.querySelector("li > ul"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`?  Are you referring to the default `$` jQuery identifier?

Comment: @Lix querySelector is a native javascript method to get elements from the dom. Basically `document.querySelectorAll(`li > ul`)` is (nearly) equivalent to `$('ul > li')`

Comment: Oh..wow.. ok then :P  I guess that's what happens when people jump straight into jQuery without diving into JS first :)

Comment: @Lix well, i recommend you to do so, it is a huge help understanding jQuery;)